# Insert certificates into an Atmel's ATWINC1500 via SAM ICE

Tags: wireless, embedded, atmel, jtag, flash-memories

With a Windows PC (*mandatory to use since atprogram is made for Windows, if someone knows how to work with that at GNU/Linux will be much appreciated*), when flashing our custom PCBs embedded hardware platforms, which use the combo **SAMD21E18A** and **ATWINC1500**, noticed that we cannnot write via **SAM ICE** the **root CA certificates** into the **ATWINC1500** (*despite is quite straightforward when testing with development boards*). And currently, the only way to flash firmware is **via SAM ICE**.

Also, the **SAM ICE** is not detected as **COM** port, which is used by a *.bat tool called `download_all.bat`.

The project can be found at ***Atmel Studio 7***, under example projects section. It's called *WINC1500 Firmware Update Project*.

Thanks a lot for your time and attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"despite is quite straightforward when testing with development board".
 This is because you have EDBG on the Dev boards. EDBG is powerful enough to debug the code as well as virtual com port (ttl Converter) connected directly to the UART pins on SAMD21 and the certificates are updated through COMPORT not PROGRAMMER.

Well when you use a SAMICE you are just programming the SAMD21 with serial bridge and the serial bridge waits for the WINC1500 firmware through UART terminal. So you have to have a FTDI cable connected to the UART pins and run the 'download_all.bat UART' on the command terminal.

Comment: Thanks @Xove, I appreciate a lot the information given. We'll have to analyze if the design allows the UART connection and make proper arrangements for the FTDI. Also, sorry if the quoted phrase offended. I was just following examples, and they work very well, the tinkering is the difficult part, and as a beginner I get frustrated quite often. Good vibes!